# $k$-Nearest Neighbor Search using examples

Tags: statistics, high-dimensional, nearest-neighbors

I want to perform [$k$-Nearest Neighbor Search](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbor_algorithm) in multidimensional space, but not using for example $L_2$-distance. I want the user to specify some "similar"-pairs examples and then perform a search using this information.

What algorithm can I use for this?

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific regarding what type of metric you want to use?

Comment: @Pedro I don't know what metric I want, but I think it must depend on data. I don't know what "similar" mean, but I have pairs(examples) which are similar and I want to extract similarity metric from this data and then perform K-Nearest Neighbor Search. Maybe I can use metric like here slide 10 http://cui.unige.ch/AI-group/teaching/dmc/09-10/cours/dm16-ml.pdf

Comment: @mrgloom So do you want to train a classifier and then apply that to determine neighbors?

Answer (score 1):

This functionality is implemented in the libAGF library. Check here: http://libagf.sourceforge.net/download.html To get an overview (the webpage is not very informative), download the library and check for the `agf_paper` in `doc` directory.

Comment: Is that paper also available separately, so that one doesn't have to download the library?